# Cannot find the source code for `tf.quantization.fake_quant_with_min_max_args`

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Where one can find the github source code for `tf.quantization.fake_quant_with_min_max_args`. Checking the [TF API documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/quantization/fake_quant_with_min_max_args), there is no link to the github source file, and I could not find one on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel for this op is defined here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ac74e1746a28b364230072d4dac5a45077326dc2/tensorflow/core/kernels/fake_quant_ops.cc#L63-L98

Comment: Why it is in a blob folder with a c++ implementation? How do you find such implementations (just googled it?)?

Comment: @MeysamSadeghi If you can't find a python file in the github , it means that the python file is generated by bazel from c++ file . So you should look it up in c++ file .